# Laravel, index en blanco

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, crud, laragon

me encuentro haciendo un doble crud en laravel y vue con Laragon. ya he hecho un crud, tengo un problema con el otro, cuando quiero entrar en el dasboar de Libros, me aparece la pagina en blanco

[image: esto me aparece]

este es mi codigo en el AutenticadeLayout

```
<ResponsiveNavLink :href="route('employees.index')" :active="route().current('employees.index')">
                            Libros
                    </ResponsiveNavLink>
```

Esta es la ruta que tengo

```
Route::resource('employees',EmployeeController::class);
```

Y por ultimo les dejo mi controlador de Empleados

```
public function index()
{
    $employees = Employee::select('employees.id','employees.name','email','phone',
    'department_id','departments.name as department')
    ->join('departments','departments.id','=','employees.department_id')
    ->paginate(10);

    $departments = Department::all();
    return Inertia::render('Employees/Index',['employees'=> $employees,
    'departments' => $departments]);
}

    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:150',
        'email' => 'required|max:80',
        'phone' => 'required|max:15',
        'department_id' => 'required|max:numeric'
    ]);
    $employee = new Employee($request->input());
    $employee->save();
    return redirect('employees');
}

   public function update(Request $request, Employee $employee)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:150',
        'email' => 'required|max:80',
        'phone' => 'required|max:15',
        'department_id' => 'required|max:numeric'
    ]);
    $employee->update($request->input());
    return redirect('employees');
}

    public function destroy(Employee $employee)
{
    $employee->delete();
    return redirect('employees');
}
```

Comment: Puedes mirar los archivos de log de Laravel, a ver si hay alguna información que te pueda ayudar. Te recomendaría que probaras con postman las rutas de las acciones del crud que te da problemas, a ver si puedes focalizar el problema en Laravel o en vue

Comment: ¿Qué postman? Perdona, la verdad apenas soy nueva programando con laravel, donde estan las rutas de las acciones del crud

Comment: postman es una aplicacion de google (la instalas en tu equipo) y con ella puedes hacer peticiones como las que hace tu front, a las url de tu back. 
las url de tu back se pueden ver con el comando de laravel `artisan route:list`. Tienes mas comandos, revisalos que puede que te ayuden en algunas otras tareas.

Comment: ya me aparecen las rutas pero parece todo en orden